# MERN project: Cann't find the cookies on client side in production environment

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

Background:
I use `express-session` to do authetication in my MERN project.
After I logged in, a session will be created and sessionId will be send to client side by cookie. So when I am trying to fetch data, server will verify my sessionId.

I run my project in dev-env, and everything goes well. I can get the cookies in chrome devtools.

BUT after I deployed my project on Vercel(Server and Client depolyed separately). When I login in my web, there are no cookies in devtools.Verification failed, no sessionId returned.

Below are my codes:

server side:

```js
//setup express-session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "PRODUCTION" ? true : false,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
    },
    name: "rd_sid",
  })
);

//setup cors
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN.split(",").map(
    (origin) => new RegExp(origin)
  ),
  allowedHeaders: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

client side:

```
export default function ajax(url, data = {}, method = "GET") {
  return new Promise((resolve, isRejected) => {
    let promise;
    // 1.1 Execute ajax request
    if (method === "GET") {
      promise = axios.get(url, {
        params: data,
        withCredentials: true,
      });
    } else if (method === "POST") {
      promise = axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true });
    }

    promise
      .then((response) => {
        // 1.2 If success, call resolve(value)
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // 1.3 If fail, do not call reject(reason) but alert error message.
        message.error("request error:" + error.message);
      });
  });
}
```

I set withCredentials to ture, and also set the header for cors. So it will solve the cross domain problem.
I try to switch `secure` , `httpOnly`, and change the cookie's name. But they seem not work.